# Изображение в ImageView появляется только после сворачивания и обратного разворачивания приложения

Tags: java, android, imageview

Я загружаю изображение с FireBase  и после вывожу его на экран с помощью ImageView. Но отображается оно лишь после того как свернуть-развернуть приложение, либо перейти на другую вкладку и вернуться обратно.
Вывод осуществляю с помощью Glide

```
   Glide.with(this).load(localFile.getPath()).into(img);
```

Comment: Посмотрите что у вас в localFile.getPath() перед вызовом отображение. Судя по описанию проблемы - там null или пустая строка. Покажите код получения `localFile.getPath()`

Comment: storeRef.getFile(localFile)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    }
                });

Comment: В комментариях код нечитаем - добавьте его в вопрос через [правку оного](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1100224/edit). И у вас, видимо, дело в том, что вы сначала отображаете картинку и только потом получаете путь к ней. По идее ваш код отображения картинки должен быть в методе `onSuccess()`